# wrong login credentials stops progress dialog

Tags: android, authentication, authorization, progressdialog

I have problem with stopping progress dialog. The BackgroundWorkerActivity is used for user authorization and registration. When user fills username and password fields on login layout, and clicks on login button, the system starts authorization and progress dialog starts to circle, and stops when message box appers that takes to the next layout. On the other hand, this progress dialog does not disappears, when user usesfwrong data or when fields are empty. The message box appears that says "Fields are empty" or "Invalid login credentials", but progress dialog remains on the layout. Here is the BackgroundWorkerActivity:

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String >{
        Context context;
        AlertDialog alertDialog ;
        BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
            context = ctx;
        }
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected String  doInBackground(String... params) {
            String type = params[0];
            String login_url = "http://sultonkhuja1111.000webhostapp.com/MobApp/auth_login.php";
            String register_url = "http://sultonkhuja1111.000webhostapp.com/MobApp/registration.php";

            if(type.equals("login")){
                try {
                    String user_name = params[1];
                    String password = params[2];
                    URL url = new URL(login_url);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                    String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                                +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                    String result="";
                    String  line="";
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                        result+=line;
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return result;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if(type.equals("register")){
                try {
                 //   String spnUsertype = params[1];
                    String txtFirst = params[1];
                    String txtLast = params[2];
                    String txtEmail = params[3];
                    String txtUsername = params[4];
                    String txtPassword = params[5];
                    String txtPhone = params[6];
                    URL url = new URL(register_url);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                    String post_data = //URLEncoder.encode("user_type","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(spnUsertype,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    URLEncoder.encode("first","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(txtFirst,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("last","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(txtLast,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(txtEmail,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(txtUsername,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(txtPassword,"UTF-8")+"&"
                            +URLEncoder.encode("phone","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(txtPhone,"UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                    String result="";
                    String  line="";
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                        result+=line;
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return result;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
      return null;
        }

     @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading Menu", "Please wait...", false, false);
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");

        }

     @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String  result) {
           // alertDialog.setMessage(result);
          //  alertDialog.show();

            if (result.contains("Successfully")) {
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i2 = new Intent(context, Login.class);
                context.startActivity(i2);
            } else if(result.contains("Congratulations")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
```

Comment: (The message box appears that says "Fields are empty" or "Invalid login credentials"). Where is the code that shows this message box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extract `loading.dismiss();` to the top of `onPostExecute`.
You are checking only the case which include a success for the user attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onPostExecute` method to

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String  result) {
           // alertDialog.setMessage(result);
          //  alertDialog.show();
               loading.dismiss();
            if (result.contains("Successfully")) {

                Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i2 = new Intent(context, Login.class);
                context.startActivity(i2);
            } else if(result.contains("Congratulations")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(i);
    }
```